# Get a <p> tag content without any class/id from another server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm writing an application with Ionic/Angular and I want to sometimes when a user clicks on a button get a paragraph content from another server/website and include/show it in my app somewhere.

But I have some issues.

I know jQuery has `.load()` method but if you want to include a div, it should have an Id then you can get it and show it in you page/app.

The paragraph I want to show from another server/website doesn't have any Id so that I can select but it is a child of other HTML tags like divs with `.row` classes just like the example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="row boxed customclass">
        <div class="row">
            <div itemprop="text">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum blah blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the content of `<p>` tag which is: **Lorem Ipsum blah blah blah** and show it in my own code maybe in a custom `<p>` tag and add other classes to it.

jQuery and Angular solutions are appreciated :)

**Update**: Since my whole idea is based on this I want to make sure that this is possible before getting started

Comment: Your major problem that you cannot request HTML from another domain via JS due to the Same Origin Policy, therefore your question is moot.

Comment: I think it is possible to get the whole html page just like any other visitor and extract the data. Also I think Cordova which Ionic uses to build application has some options for CORS to handle this. But thanks for your reply anyway :)

Comment: It is possible if CORS is enabled on the domain, but that is highly unlikely unless you're calling an API intended for client consumption. If CORS is not enabled on the domain there is nothing you can do.

Comment: @mamos98 Ya, it has. To reply to your question, you can pass any relevant selector to `load()` method

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok then Thanks.

Comment: @A.Wolff any CSS selectors can be used?

Comment: @mamos98 Ya you could pass `.load('url .row p')`. But of course, you need to hanlde the cross origin request in some way like Rory said

Comment: You would need to use a proxy either on your server or third party service to retrieve the page from other site.

Comment: @charlietfl Ya. Im not ionic developer but sounds like you can quite easily run your own proxy server  http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/#theioniccliproxyserver

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you. If this you was entered this as an answer I would check it as the answer to my question, you can still do it but thanks again! I think I might need to develop a small version of the application to see if things go right or I need to think of something else.

Comment: @charlietfl thank you. I will think about it :)